# dropout(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not str when using Bert with Huggingface

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model

My code was working fine and when I tried to run it today without changing anything I got the following error:

```
dropout(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not str
```

Would appreciate if help could be provided.
Could be an issue with the data loader?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at the guidelines before posting a question. If you want to get answer from SO, your question needs to be reproducible in order for others to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. 

This could be a problem anywhere within your code.

Answer (score 58):

if you use HuggingFace, this [information](https://huggingface.co/transformers/migration.html) could be useful. I have same error and fix it with adding parameter *return_dict=False* in model class before dropout:
outputs = model(**inputs, return_dict=False)

Answer (score 20):

I was also working on same repo. There is a class probably named Bert_Arch that inherits the nn.Module and this class has a overriden method named forward. Inside forward method just add the parameter 'return_dict=False' to the self.bert() method call.
Replace

```
_, cls_hs = self.bert(sent_id, attention_mask=mask)
```

with

```
_, cls_hs = self.bert(sent_id, attention_mask=mask, return_dict=False)
```

Answer (score 20):

If you are using the Hugging Face transformers library, this error pops up when running code written in v3 on the transformers v4 library. To resolve it, simply add `return_dict=False` when loading the model as follows:

```
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
outputs = model(**inputs, return_dict=False)
```

or

```
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased", return_dict=False)
outputs = model(**inputs)
```

I hope this helps. It worked for me.

Reference: https://huggingface.co/transformers/migration.html

Comment: Second option worked for me