# TypeError: linear(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not str

Tags: python, pytorch, bert-language-model

so ive been trying to work on some example of bert that i found on github as its the first time im trying to use bert and see how it works. The respiratory im working with is the following: https://github.com/prateekjoshi565/Fine-Tuning-BERT/blob/master/Fine_Tuning_BERT_for_Spam_Classification.ipynb

im using a different dataset however im getting the issue TypeError: linear(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not str" and honestly i dont know what im doing wrong. is there anyone that could help me?

the code ive been using is the following:

```
# convert class weights to tensor
weights= torch.tensor(class_wts,dtype=torch.float)
weights = weights.to(device)

# loss function
cross_entropy  = nn.NLLLoss(weight=weights) 

# number of training epochs
epochs = 10

def train():
  
  model.train()

  total_loss, total_accuracy = 0, 0
  
  # empty list to save model predictions
  total_preds=[]
  
  # iterate over batches
  for step,batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
    
    # progress update after every 50 batches.
    if step % 50 == 0 and not step == 0:
      print('  Batch {:>5,}  of  {:>5,}.'.format(step, len(train_dataloader)))

    # push the batch to gpu
    batch = [r.to(device) for r in batch]
 
    sent_id, mask, labels = batch

    # clear previously calculated gradients 
    model.zero_grad()        

    # get model predictions for the current batch
    preds = model(sent_id, mask)

    # compute the loss between actual and predicted values
    loss = cross_entropy(preds, labels)

    # add on to the total loss
    total_loss = total_loss + loss.item()

    # backward pass to calculate the gradients
    loss.backward()

    # clip the the gradients to 1.0. It helps in preventing the exploding gradient problem
    torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)

    # update parameters
    optimizer.step()

    # model predictions are stored on GPU. So, push it to CPU
    preds=preds.detach().cpu().numpy()

    # append the model predictions
    total_preds.append(preds)

  # compute the training loss of the epoch
  avg_loss = total_loss / len(train_dataloader)
  
  # predictions are in the form of (no. of batches, size of batch, no. of classes).
  # reshape the predictions in form of (number of samples, no. of classes)
  total_preds  = np.concatenate(total_preds, axis=0)

  #returns the loss and predictions
  return avg_loss, total_preds

def evaluate():
  
  print("\nEvaluating...")
  
  # deactivate dropout layers
  model.eval()

  total_loss, total_accuracy = 0, 0
  
  # empty list to save the model predictions
  total_preds = []

  # iterate over batches
  for step,batch in enumerate(val_dataloader):
    
    # Progress update every 50 batches.
    if step % 50 == 0 and not step == 0:
      
      # Calculate elapsed time in minutes.
      elapsed = format_time(time.time() - t0)
            
      # Report progress.
      print('  Batch {:>5,}  of  {:>5,}.'.format(step, len(val_dataloader)))

    # push the batch to gpu
    batch = [t.to(device) for t in batch]

    sent_id, mask, labels = batch

    # deactivate autograd
    with torch.no_grad():
      
      # model predictions
      preds = model(sent_id, mask)

      # compute the validation loss between actual and predicted values
      loss = cross_entropy(preds,labels)

      total_loss = total_loss + loss.item()

      preds = preds.detach().cpu().numpy()

      total_preds.append(preds)

  # compute the validation loss of the epoch
  avg_loss = total_loss / len(val_dataloader) 

  # reshape the predictions in form of (number of samples, no. of classes)
  total_preds  = np.concatenate(total_preds, axis=0)

  return avg_loss, total_preds

# set initial loss to infinite
best_valid_loss = float('inf')

# empty lists to store training and validation loss of each epoch
train_losses=[]
valid_losses=[]

#for each epoch
for epoch in range(epochs):
     
    print('\n Epoch {:} / {:}'.format(epoch + 1, epochs))
    
    #train model
    train_loss, _ = train()
    
    #evaluate model
    valid_loss, _ = evaluate()
    
    #save the best model
    if valid_loss < best_valid_loss:
        best_valid_loss = valid_loss
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'saved_weights.pt')
    
    # append training and validation loss
    train_losses.append(train_loss)
    valid_losses.append(valid_loss)
    
    print(f'\nTraining Loss: {train_loss:.3f}')
    print(f'Validation Loss: {valid_loss:.3f}')
```

the traceback i receive is:

```
Epoch 1 / 10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-c5138ddf6b25> in <module>()
     12 
     13     #train model
---> 14     train_loss, _ = train()
     15 
     16     #evaluate model

5 frames
<ipython-input-103-3236a6e339dd> in train()
     24 
     25     # get model predictions for the current batch
---> 26     preds = model(sent_id, mask)
     27 
     28     # compute the loss between actual and predicted values

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

<ipython-input-99-9ebdcf410f97> in forward(self, sent_id, mask)
     28       _, cls_hs = self.bert(sent_id, attention_mask=mask)
     29 
---> 30       x = self.fc1(cls_hs)
     31 
     32       x = self.relu(x)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
     92 
     93     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
---> 94         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
     95 
     96     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1751     if has_torch_function_variadic(input, weight):
   1752         return handle_torch_function(linear, (input, weight), input, weight, bias=bias)
-> 1753     return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
   1754 
   1755 

TypeError: linear(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not str
```

Comment: Did their version work for you before you made changes?
Did you tokenize your data beforehand? 
If your answers are yes, yes, can you please also post your dataloader?

Answer (score 9):

I've been working on this repo too.
Motivated by the answer provided on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65082243/dropout-argument-input-position-1-must-be-tensor-not-str-when-using-bert). There is a class probably named Bert_Arch that inherits the nn.Module and this class has a overriden method named forward. Inside forward method just add the parameter 'return_dict=False' to the self.bert() method call. Like so:

```
_, cls_hs = self.bert(sent_id, attention_mask=mask, return_dict=False)
```

This worked for me.