# TypeError: dropout(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not str Bert Model

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, pytorch, bert-language-model

Hi I encounter this error when I was training my Bert Model for sentiment analysis, where my classes have 3 outcomes and my input data is text.

So I got the above error when I am training the model. I have searched some of the guides and tried to set this parameter to my bert model `bert_model = BertModel.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME,return_dict=False)`
but I am still getting the same error as before. I am using 'bert-base-cased' pretrained model

```
# Function for a single training iteration
def train_epoch(model, data_loader, loss_fn, optimizer, device, scheduler, n_examples):
    model = model.train()
    losses = []
    correct_predictions = 0
    
    for d in data_loader:
        input_ids = d["input_ids"].to(device)
        attention_mask = d["attention_mask"].to(device)
        targets = d["targets"].to(device)
        
        outputs = model(
            input_ids=input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask
        )
        
        _, preds = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)
        loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)
        correct_predictions += torch.sum(preds == targets)
        losses.append(loss.item())
        
        # Backward prop
        loss.backward()
        
        # Gradient Descent
        nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm=1.0)
        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    return correct_predictions.double() / n_examples, np.mean(losses)
```

```
%%time

history = defaultdict(list)
best_accuracy = 0

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    
    # Show details 
    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{EPOCHS}")
    print("-" * 10)
    
    train_acc, train_loss = train_epoch(
        model,
        train_data_loader,
        loss_fn,
        optimizer,
        device,
        scheduler,
        len(df_train)
    )
    
    print(f"Train loss {train_loss} accuracy {train_acc}")
    
    # Get model performance (accuracy and loss)
    val_acc, val_loss = eval_model(
        model,
        val_data_loader,
        loss_fn,
        device,
        len(df_val)
    )
    
    print(f"Val   loss {val_loss} accuracy {val_acc}")
    print()
    
    history['train_acc'].append(train_acc)
    history['train_loss'].append(train_loss)
    history['val_acc'].append(val_acc)
    history['val_loss'].append(val_loss)
    
    # If we beat prev performance
    if val_acc > best_accuracy:
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'best_model_state.bin')
        best_accuracy = val_acc
```

Comment: You need to check this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65082243/dropout-argument-input-position-1-must-be-tensor-not-str-when-using-bert
I'm sure this will help you.