# How to add a dense layer on top of SentenceTransformer?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, sentence-transformers

In this tutorial ([Train and Fine-Tune Sentence Transformers Models](https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-train-sentence-transformers)) they go through creating a SentenceTransformer by combining a word embedding module with a pooling layer:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, models

## Step 1: use an existing language model
word_embedding_model = models.Transformer('distilroberta-base')

## Step 2: use a pool function over the token embeddings
pooling_model = models.Pooling(word_embedding_model.get_word_embedding_dimension())

## Join steps 1 and 2 using the modules argument
model = SentenceTransformer(modules=[word_embedding_model, pooling_model])

# model.encode("Hi there")  # => works fine
```

And then they say:

> If necessary, additional layers can be added, for example, dense, bag of words, and convolutional.

I tried to add a dense layer on top of the model, but I'm getting an error:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, models

## Step 1: use an existing language model
word_embedding_model = models.Transformer('distilroberta-base')

## Step 2: use a pool function over the token embeddings
pooling_model = models.Pooling(word_embedding_model.get_word_embedding_dimension())

##  My Dense Layer
dense_layer = torch.nn.Linear(pooling_model.get_sentence_embedding_dimension(), 128)

## Join steps 1 and 2 using the modules argument
model = SentenceTransformer(modules=[word_embedding_model, pooling_model, dense_layer])
```

And when I run `model.encode("hi there")` I get:

> TypeError: linear(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not dict

I found the same error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65082243/dropout-argument-input-position-1-must-be-tensor-not-str-when-using-bert) but using `BertModel.from_pretrained`, not `models.Transformer`. The suggested answer (passing the argument `return_dict=False`) doesn't work:

```
word_embedding_model = models.Transformer('distilroberta-base', return_dict=False)
```

> TypeError: Transformer.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'return_dict'

Any ideas how to add a dense layer correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.sbert.net/docs/package_reference/models.html#sentence_transformers.models.Dense), replace this line:

```
dense_layer = torch.nn.Linear(pooling_model.get_sentence_embedding_dimension(), 128)
```

with the following:

```
dense_layer = models.Dense(pooling_model.get_sentence_embedding_dimension(), 128)
```